# Make is ignoring compiler flags

Tags: windows, g++, gnu-make

I have a project that I'm able to compile without issues on Ubuntu. The Makefile at https://github.com/avalon-lang/avaloni/blob/master/Makefile is the one I'm trying to adapt for Windows 10.
I have MingW-w64 installed and GNU Make-32.
When I run make against the Makefile, CFLAGS and other flags passed to the compiler are not shown leaving spaces in the echoed output instead of the compiler flags. Therefore, files required for a successful compilation are not found.

I tried to replace the variables CFLAGS, SYSINC and INC with their content but nothing changed. They are simply ignored as if make deleted them.

```
cc          := g++
cflags      := -std=c++11 -g -Wall -pedantic -DDEBUG -fopenmp
ldpaths     := -LC:/Boost/lib
rdpaths     := -Wl,-rpath=C:/Boost/lib
ldflags     := -lboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-x64-1_68 -lboost_system-mgw81-mt-x64-1_68 -fopenmp
src_dir     := src
inc         := -Isrc -Ideps/qpp
sysinc      := -isystem deps/boost -isystem deps/eigen
build_dir   := build
bin_dir     := bin
target      := $(bin_dir)/avaloni.exe

src_ext     := cpp
sources     := $(shell dir $(src_dir)\*.$(src_ext) /b /s)
objects     := $(patsubst $(src_dir)\%,$(build_dir)\%,$(sources:.$(src_ext)=.o))

install_dir := C:/Avalon
sdk_path    := C:/Avalon/AvalonSdk


.PHONY: all
all: setup $(target)

$(target): $(objects)
    $(cc) $^ -o $(target) $(ldpaths) $(ldflags) $(rdpaths)

$(build_dir)\%.o: $(src_dir)\%.$(src_ext)
    @if not exist "$(dir $@)" mkdir $(dir $@)
    $(cc) $(cflags) $(sysinc) $(inc) -c -o $@ $< #!!! This is the problem line.
```

During compilation, I expect a line like the following:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -pedantic -DDEBUG -fopenmp -isystem deps/boost -isystem deps/eigen -Isrc -Ideps/qpp -c -o file.o file.cpp
```

But I get:

```
g++    -c -o file.o file.cpp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that (a) you're using non-standard variables to hold your compiler flags, and (b) your pattern rule doesn't match.

Because of (b), make chooses the built-in rule for creating an object file and because of (a), none of your flags are used in the built-in rule.

The reason your pattern rule doesn't match is that GNU make doesn't support backslashes in pathnames.  You *must* use forward slashes in all your rules:

```
$(build_dir)/%.o: $(src_dir)/%.$(src_ext)
  ...
```

Comment: For b) make doesn't seem to care about whether I use forward slashes or backward slashes. To be on the safe side, I'm using forward slashes wherever the don't pose a problem.
For a) I'm not sure how using "standard variables" helps because as stated in the question, even if I replace those variables with plain compiler flags, the problem is not solved. The flags simple disappear. 
What am I missing?

Comment: @NtwaliB.: What MadScientist is saying is that a built-in rule is activating, and if you named your variables to match convention, then your values would be picked up by and used in the built-in rule.  Eliminating variables gives you zero chance to affect the built-in rule.  Of course, if your goal is to define your own rule (which it seems to be) then the variable names used in the built-in don't matter.

Comment: @BenVoigt That makes sense. I've not been able to find the expected names for "standard variables" which I assume to mean cflags, ldflags and the others, for Windows that is. I did try to capitalize them to no avail. Any directions/hints to docs or elsewhere?

Comment: @NtwaliB.: Try here for documentation on standard rules: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Comment: @BenVoigt I'll be damned! Changing CFLAGS to CXXFLAGS got me the expected output. Now trying to get the others to work. Will accept the answer once I got it all figured out.